Fan noise due to Harmonics while running on UPS?
When mains is not available, ceiling fan will run on UPS and create a  different sound/noise. I know that it is due to harmonics. But how can we remove this noise?
By getting a high quality  inverter, having a filter which gives pure sine  wave output?
Can someone please elaborate?
Update: Responding to comment. I am living in subcontinent and if in any case i have no other option but to run fan on UPS

Why would you run a ceiling fan with an UPS to begin with, as UPSes are generally used for keeping some critical computing or life support system on, and to shut down the computer system gracefully when batteries are almost depleted. Can you just change the fan to non-UPS supply? The fan clearly isn't intended to run on anything else than sine wave.

Square wave output UPS?

Look for a UPS or inverter that provides a pure sine wave output.Pure sine wave inverters produce power that closely mimics the smooth waveform of utility-supplied electricity.
